# VirtualBox Screen Resolution Too Small During Installation

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I'm trying to install a new Ubuntu distribution using VirtualBox, but on this particular distro (Pop!_OS), the initial screen resolution in VirtualBox is too small for the guided installation. There are buttons that I need to click, but I can't see them, move my mouse to them, or resize the window.

I know the usual solution is to install the Guest Additions for VirtualBox, but when I select "Devices" -> "Insert Guest Additions CD image..." I get an error since the virtual optical drive is already being used by the distro's installation image. How can I increase the screen resolution so I can continue through the installation?

Answer (score 19):

Boot the installer in EFI mode not legacy-BIOS mode.

It's Settings->System->Enable EFI (special OSes only).

I just tested this with POP!_OS 20.10. BIOS mode: tiny 800x600 window. EFI mode: window is large enough to fit the installer.

If you do get an 800x600 window, you can also move the installer window so that you can see the desktop, right-click on the desktop, choose "Display Settings", and increase the resolution.

Comment: This worked for me (changing the display resolution).

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me with the newest **Elementary 6.0**. Now I can see the buttons for the installer in VirtualBox window.

Answer (score 5):

Encountered same problem a week ago.

If you can't see the title bar to move it, hold down <kbd>left-Alt</kbd> then left click anywhere in the window, you will see hand tool to move the window screen and you will see the buttons which were not visible before.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to add an additional optical drive to the virtual machine, which allows the guest additions image to mount after booting into the installation image.

1. While the virtual machine is off, go to "Settings" -> "Storage" and add an optical drive to the IDE Controller (there are probably several ways to do this, but this is the route I took).
2. Start the virtual machine and boot into your installation image.
3. Go to "Devices" -> "Insert Guest Additions CD image..."
4. A terminal window will open and the installation will begin.
5. Once the installation finishes, ignore any warnings or errors and resize your virtual machine window to complete the installation of the operating system.

Note: You will receive a warning during the installation of the guest additions that effectively says they cannot be completely installed because the removable media cannot be restarted. However, I found that I was still able to resize the virtual machine and continue with the installation of the OS. The guest additions obviously did not persist once booted into the newly installed OS and needed to be reinstalled.

Comment: These instructions were perfect for me except for the end of the process. I couldn't simply resize the screen. I had to go into the VM's system settings and select a larger display. And then I could continue running the installer.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the Screen resolution of the Ubuntu worked for me.

Go to Displays Setting and change Resolution.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please adjust VM "`VirtualBox`" 's "Max Guest Screen Size" and it's “Scale Factor”,

also, the Guest Machine's “Scale Factor” should be adjusted.

Just use "`Debian`" via "`VirtualBox`" for an example, please do the same

Functional operations on "`Ubuntu`".

1. VM scale factor and max screen size:

click `VirtualBox` APP, then you see "`Oracle Vm VirtualBox Manager`",

move your mouse to top menu, found out `VirtualBox`logo, select

"`Preference`", then enter "`VirtualBox – General`", click `Display`,

Choose "`Maximum screen size`" to "`Hint`" with Width "`1280`" and

Height "`800`", and adjust "`Scale Factor`" to "`200%`", then click

"`OK`".

2. Guest scale factor:

When you enter `VirtualBox` APP, then you see "`Oracle Vm VirtualBox Manager`",

found out your guest machine name button, as mine is "`linux_debian_11`",

you will see "`Power Off`" under the name of your guest machine.

Please found out your guest machine "`Menu Box Button`", that is at the right

of your guest machine name, right-click your "`Menu Box`" or single click your

"`Guest Machine Box`", choose "`Settings`", then you will enter your guest

machine's "`General`", mine is "`linux_debian_11 – General`", then click

"`Display`", and adjust "`Scale Factor`" to "`200%`"(the same as `Scale Factor`

On virtual machine's "`General`").

3. Restart your Host machine, Mac/Windows.

Answer (score 0):

In view settings turn the scale of virtual screen on 200% then reboot guest system, turn the skale to 100%, then reboot system again, this will help to render installation window correctly

Answer (score 0):

Viewer > Virtual Screen Resizing > set to 1024 x 768 or other.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If it's too small to install you can toggle the text-based installation. It's not so nice like the GUI installation, but works to.